# Determining without server access with which url you can access website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, url, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to find out all possible urls, direct links so access a website. 
More specifically a stock site in yahoo finance. I've already discovered
a couple by guessing but i need a more comprehensive list. As i would like to access them via their unique id but not the ticker symbol
I'd be very grateful for hints on where to look in development tools or any other, better mention it, legal method to get this info

Example URL:
https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA

Edit: is it be possible to utilize their search engine without loading the full web page in my script?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to know all valid urls in a domain. This not possible unless the site has sitemap file and you can crawl it to get list of valid urls. But mind you even that would not be a comprehensive list.

Comment: You understood correctly. That's what i assumed unfortunatly. Thank you for your help anyway!